# Debugging javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found

Tags: java, android, ssl, nginx, websocket

I'm trying to use [a WebSocket client](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client) (on Android) to connect to an NGINX proxy via secure wss.

I have two servers, one in the intranet and one AWS.

When trying to connect to the local server, the connection fails with a `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.`

When connecting to the server on AWS I get a `com.neovisionaries.ws.client.OpeningHandshakeException: The status code of the opening handshake response is not '101 Switching Protocols'. The status line is: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found` **which is to be expected** because the NGINX instance on AWS has not been configured to switch the protocol and connect to the upstream websocket server. This is being developed on the local server. But this is an indication that TLS/SSL is working on AWS, which is enough for me.

Also, a connection to `wss://echo.websocket.org` succeeds and messages are getting echoed back.

**Now, here's the odd thing**: The NGINX instance on AWS, which runs inside a docker container, has the same codebase as the one on the local machine. Both are NGINXs running in a docker container, the volumes mounted the same way, with very similar configuration files. The only thing that differs is the domain name and the associated SSL certificates.

Those are DV certificates from Comodo (Positive SSL). I've also tried LetsEncrypt certificates with the same result.

I don't understand why the two containers behave so differently, and I can't find a reason to blame the servers hosting the docker service (both Ubuntu 14.04)

So I'm wanting to dissect the certificates (and their chain) in the Android client application.

**How can I print the contents of the certificate chain?**

Chrome Browser JavaScript wss connections to the local server do work, from the Android device as well as from PCs.

**~~~~ Update ~~~~ Please don't answer to the stuff below, as I will split it into a separate question**

Ok, I progressed **with the help from @CommonsWare**. Here are new questions, which start getting interesting.

The server in the intranet hosts a self-signed certificate as a catchall https response. The logic behind it is that if someone from the internet visits the IP address of the public IP of that intranet via https://<IP-INTRANET-GATEWAY>, it gets served that dummy certificate. The reason for this is that it should not return the certificate for the intranet (https://intranet.example.com).

Several domain names with different certificates point to that IP address https://intranet.example.com, https://testing.intranet.example.com, so there are multiple SSL certificates served for this IP

In NGINX it would be:

```
server {      
  listen 443;
  server_name _;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/self-signed-dummy.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/self-signed-dummy.key;
  location / {
    return 404;
  }  
}  

server {      
  listen 443;
  server_name intranet.example.com;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/intranet.example.com.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/intranet.example.com.key;
  location / {
    ...
  }  
}  

server {      
  listen 443;
  server_name testing.intranet.example.com;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/testing.intranet.example.com.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/testing.intranet.example.com.key;
  location / {
    ...
  }  
}
```

This is a difference to the server on AWS, which has no self-signed certificate on it.

Any idea why the client could get served the dummy certificate?

Also, how can I dump the certificate whithout an exception, for example in order to analyze the certificate (+chain) returned by the AWS server?

Using a plain `HttpURLConnection` with https works without problems.

Comment: `getCause()` on the `SSLHandshakeException` probably returns a `CertPathValidatorException`. That has a `getCertPath()` method, which returns a `CertPath`, which has a `getCertificates()` method representing the chain.

Comment: Yeah, thanks! "Internet Widgits Pty Ltd" and I wonder why that is getting served. You helped me. Put in in an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getCause()` on the `SSLHandshakeException` probably returns a `CertPathValidatorException`, given the text of the error. That has a `getCertPath()` method, which returns a `CertPath`, which has a `getCertificates()` method representing the chain. If needed, those certificates should be able to be cast to `X509Certificate` objects, which give you a variety of details about the cert.

> "Internet Widgits Pty Ltd" and I wonder why that is getting served

I don't know, but an Internet search on that string does not sound promising.

Comment: I've updated the question. My NGINX server on the intranet serves a dummy certificate for all default hits which don't match a specific domain. It is that certificate.

Comment: @DanielF: "Any idea why the client could get served the dummy certificate?" -- if the server serves ordinary pages in addition to the WebSocket stuff, see what an ordinary HTTPS request behaves like (e.g., use OkHttp3 or `HttpURLConnection`). If that succeeds, perhaps you need to do something different for WebSocket setup. "how can I dump the certificate whithout an exception" -- the only way I know of is to implement your own `X509TrustManager`, so you can get the certificate chain for validation, but that's a pain.

Comment: Thanks. I just checked by replacing that dummy certificate with the one of the domain in question, and it works. Obviously this is a workaround, but it's a good starting point. I'm splitting the question into a new one, and will test your recommendation. I'm not keen on implementing a custom X509TrustManager, as things might break further down the road (ie in a couple of years when changes are being made to the certificates). Also it's odd that WebViews have no problems with this. It may be an implementation issue of the WebSocket library, which is why I'll next check your https recommendation

Comment: Do you know how I can get the content of `getCertPath()` without being in an `SSLHandshakeException`? Like in a healthy application flow? Could you add this to your answer? I'd like to check the CertPath of the AWS server.

Comment: FYI: HttpURLConnection succeeds.

Comment: @DanielF: "Like in a healthy application flow?" -- no, sorry. Again, the only way I know of to get the cert chain (in any form) is if you are part of the certification process, in the form of an `X509TrustManager`. There might be another approach, but I don't know of it.